# Do we need hashCode Implementation for TreeMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashcode, treemap, comparable

I was testing the behaviour of `TreeMap` and understood the process of sorting. However  I am still in the confusing thought that, for retrieval does the custom key class needs to override the hashCode method. Having said that, I have searched enough of google but could not find any justifiable answer.

Below is the example which I worked with.

```
class Dog implements Comparable<Dog> {
    String color;
    int size;

Dog(String c, int s) {
    color = c;
    size = s;
 }

int hc;

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    hc = super.hashCode();
    return hc;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Dog o) {
    return this.color.compareTo(o.color);
}
}
```

Test Code for testing the TreeMap..

```
public class TestHashMap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog d1 = new Dog("a", 1);
        Dog d2 = new Dog("b", 2);
        Dog d3 = new Dog("c", 3);
        Dog d4 = new Dog("d", 4);
        Dog d5 = new Dog("e", 5);

        Dog d = new Dog("c", 3);

        TreeMap<Dog, Integer> hm = new TreeMap<>();
        hm.put(d1, 10);
        hm.put(d2, 15);
        hm.put(d3, 5);
        hm.put(d4, 20);
        hm.put(d5, 25);

        System.out.println("value is :" + hm.get(d));
    }
}
```

Irrespective of I implement hashCode method or not the value is retrieved correctly, However when debugging , always hashcode method is called , so I am confused if really hashCode implementation is mandatory.

Could anybody please help in understanding the correct behaviour of retrieval from TreeMap.

Please do not copy paste java doc from TreeMap.

Comment: TreeMap definitely does not call `hashCode`---unless you force it to by calling `TreeMap#hashCode()`.

Comment: A tree is not a hash table. There is no need to calculate hashes.

Comment: Please go through the docs of TreeMap. It needs a class which implements Comparable interface or a Comparator passed to the constructor of it. It only calls the implementation of these interfaces

Comment: Have you checked the actual stack trace when your breakpoint inside `hashCode` is triggered? Which method is the direct caller of `hashCode`?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik : Really sorry for confusion. I was calling hashcode Method in sysout hence confused. Apologies for confusion

Comment: I also got confused with one of this blog http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2007/07/13/treemap-vs-hashmap/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `hashCode()` is called as a part of default `toString()` implementation. Since you haven't implemented your own `toString()`, I'd suspect you printed a `Dog` somewhere in your code which caused the method invocation.

Comment: The printed `hm.get(d)` is an `Integer`, not `Dog`.

Comment: @Danstahr. : Yes you are right I did the same blunder.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that **it was my mistake** that I was explicitly calling hashCode() in toString() method which created this confusion.

Nonetheless the conclusion is , For TreeMap it follows the Comparable Interface implementation and does not follow hashCode and equals implementation.

Comment: Maybe your debugger is calling `toString()` and the `hashCode()` in consequence? I run your code on debug in IntelliJ, but execution never stopped on breakpoint in `Dog.hashCode()`. Or maybe you run different code, than you posted.

Comment: Yes the posted code does not have it. It was my code and I missed System.out.println copying.

Comment: Do note, however, that `It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural orderings be consistent with equals. This is so because sorted sets (and sorted maps) without explicit comparators behave "strangely" when they are used with elements (or keys) whose natural ordering is inconsistent with equals. In particular, such a sorted set (or sorted map) violates the general contract for set (or map), which is defined in terms of the equals method.`---and, whenever you override `equals`, you *must* override `hashCode` to match.